# SSL сертификаты перевод из crt в pem

Tags: ssl, сертификат, openssl

Изучаю openssl, хочу: создать сертификат центра сертификации и импортировать его в браузер, а также сертификат для сайта.

Разобрался, что сертификат для браузера создается через makecert в формате crt. А для openssl через openssl в формате pem. Как из crt формата перевести в pem?

Если коротко, задача: создать сертификат для firefox, чтобы при запуске openssl s_server и подключении браузером на https://127.0.0.1:4433/ не вылетало предупреждение о непроверенном сертификате.

Answer (score 6):

**Конвертирование файла DER (.crt .cer .der) в PEM:**

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem
```

**Конвертирование файла PEM в DER:**

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.der
```

**Конвертирование файла PKCS#12, который содержит приватный ключ и сертификат в PEM:**

```
openssl pkcs12 -in keyStore.pfx -out keyStore.pem -nodes
```

**Конвертирование PEM файла и приватного ключа в PKCS#12:**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privateKey.key -in certificate.crt -certfile CACert.crt
```

Comment: Ещё бы знать, что означают все эти операции и зачем их выполнять. )

Answer (score -3):

Не нужно не чего переводить в опенсервере и так все работает!!!

в конфигурационном файле апача:

SSLCertificateFile      "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/Имя_сайта.crt"

SSLCertificateKeyFile   "%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/Имя_сайта.key"

Comment: OpenServer тут вообще ни при чём.

Comment: Вероятно, вы перепутали OpenSSL и OpenServer. Вопрос касается первого.

Comment: Да, точно, ну извините за невнимательность((